# reload parent page from iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, refresh

I have a login form and it is in iframe and its only appear as popup when you click login button

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="262" src="login.php"></iframe>
```

what I try to do is after successfully login I want main page to be reloaded (refresh index.php) if password is wrong its should display an error in iframe. is it possible to do this with jquery using get / set

Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For reloading the top window you can do the following:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

Or if you want to redirect to another URL, just write this:

```
window.top.location = URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
No jQuery needed...

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

Comment: it didn't work. I have this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null

Answer (score 0):

This **worked** for me (but using Javascript),

```
// In parent
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("MY_IFRAME").onload = function() {
    top.location.reload();
  }
}
```